# JavaScript automatically sorts array?

Tags: javascript

1.I need to compare X coordinates with Y coordinates, I log all X coordinates in  2.xlog, and all Y coordinates in Ylog. 
3. JavaScript automatically sorts the arrays so..... ?
     var rx = Math.round(x) ;
     var ry = Math.round(y) ;

```
  xlog.push(rx);
  ylog.push(ry);
```

Comment: Before posting the questions do some research. It will help you to get answers already existing and also avoid the duplicate questions from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript won't automatically sort the array for you. You have at least two options:

1. Create a function that inserts at the appropriate index via [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (after finding that index, presumably by looping with `for` or [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or using the much newer [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) [you'll need a shim for `Array#find` on some browsers]). For instance, `ylog.splice(2, 0, ry);` will insert `ry` at index 2 in the array.
2. Call [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) after each `push` (but this is inefficient).